# JQuery Parsing XML to variable

Tags: jquery, xml

I am looking to parse XML data (using this URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ijudAdhLGmg?v=2) and get the contents of the title element and store it in a variable so I can use it later in my script. I am new to JQuery and I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: cant you just add &alt=json to the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`.psrseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) for the parsing

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ijudAdhLGmg?v=2',
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success:function(data){
    //console.log(data);
        var xml    = data,
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml   = $(xmlDoc),
        $mediaDes = $xml.find("media\\:description").text();
        console.log($mediaDes );
    }
});
```

the `data` in the success callback contains the `xml`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6yZT/6/)

Comment: @user1126921 you will have to parse the xml and append the wanted values using `append` or `appendTo` functions you can search them

Answer (score 2):

code below will fetch the xml from the url and get the title

```
$.ajax({
   url:"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ijudAdhLGmg?v=2",
   dataType:"xml",
   crossDomain: true,
   success:function(html){
      var title = $(html).find("title")[0];
   }
});
```

however the problem you might face is the cross site problem, where modern browser will not allow ajax to call an url that not the same as the host

Answer (score 1):

You can check the jQuery online doc.

This one is for jQuery to parse XML: [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var xml    = "your xml string here",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml   = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("title");
```